# Getting Exception while running a unit test for c++ in vs 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, tdd

I have followed this walkthrough to create a test project and a dll project.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh270864(v=vs.110).aspx

Now problem is that when i write a unit test and include (#include "..\RootFinder\RootFinder.h") and run unit test I got exception.

Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.

I set a breakpoint inside unit test, tried to debug but only exception message is showed. No tests run.
Why is exception coming.

However if i make same project with same settings in visual studio 2008 it works fine. I converted 2008 solution to 2010 and then run the test, but exception came as I run unit tests.

Comment: In the unit test, wrap all the code in a try/catch handler and set a breakpoint in the catch block. When the debugger hits there, inspect the Exception and see what you can learn from it.

Comment: it didnt enter the code, i try the try catch but debugger doesnt hit it, it dont enter the function, it is not in the code. may be I am missing some references or something. i have followed all the step from the walkthrough, it builds fine but when run test it gives exception,

Comment: I didn't look at the walkthrough, so I don't know how much work this is, but what if you were to follow the walkthrough using VS2010 instead of doing it in 2008 and converting the solution?

Comment: @JeffH i have done that as well, but it doesnt works,

Answer (score 2):

please refer to the following fix:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2734667
It helped me to solve the same problem.

Comment: It worked partially. After adding those files, the tests worked, but the visual studio test panel is not displayed anymore.

Comment: This worked for me in VS2010. @AquilaRapax: Which test panel are you talking about? check Tools > Windows > TestResults if that is what you are talking about.